# What are the express equivalents to Rails' asset pipeline and asset paths

Tags: node.js, express, asset-pipeline, cdn

I'm looking to solve two problems:

- Rewriting URLs in production to use a CDN URL instead of the original domain name
- Concatenation and minification of client side JS and CSS

There seems to be a few options for for achieving the latter, for example asset-smasher. However I'm finding it hard to find a good solution for rewriting images and other assets. Any libraries out there to help?

Thanks!